# Deleting files from google cloud storage through app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage

I have developed an app using Flask and App Engine. I was able to upload file in google cloud storage, but not able to delete file.

I am using: `files.delete('/gs/bucket/file.pdf')` to delete a file.

App executes this line, but file is not deleted from cloud storage.

According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/functions#delete, it should work.

It is not even working in local development server also.

Please let me know, what I am missing or is there any better to achieve this?

Comment: can you show output of files.listdir('/gs/bucket')

Comment: files.listdir('/gs/mybucket') is showing proper output. I cross checked in cloud storage. Sorry for the delayed reply.

Comment: `'/gs/bucket'` is different to `'/gs/mybucket'`. In your question/delete call you use the former

Comment: Its 'bucket'. The problem is solved, I was sending file to be deleted from the bucket through html form, which was not handled properly.It is working now. Thanks.